# how to jump back to line in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

i have "if" loop and want that in my "then" part the command will be "jump back to line...and run the script all over from that line". how do I write it

```
if [ -s file.txt ] 
then
    jump to command \ jump to line ....
else 
    <command> 
fi
```

thanks

Comment: Put everything in a loop and use `continue` to restart the loop.

Comment: You could also use `goto`.

Comment: That's the second time today I've seen people use the term `"if" loop` - `if` is not a loop, ITYM `statement` or `construct` instead of `loop`. You should use a loop, probably `while`, not an `if`. Ah, now I see the first time was [you too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73852773/1745001).

Comment: you are right, IF for condition :)

Comment: if I use goto command, i mention line number or the command on that line?

Comment: Don't use a goto command. If some condition exists that should redirect the control flow of your code then make it clear and obvious in the structure of your code.

Comment: There is no `goto` command in `bash`  (or other POSIX-like shells).

Comment: please update the question with sample code that shows your real world issue; the current `if/then/jump/else/command/fi` could be replaced simply with `command`

Answer (score 0):

How to avoid `goto` and start processing from a certain point? As an example you want to start over the processing until a flag has value 5.
The comments mentioned a `loop`. A dirty loop is something like this:

```
startfrom=0
flag=0
# Dirty loop, look to second code fragment for cleanup
while :; do
  if ((startfrom==0)); then
   echo "First time, all statements"
   ((startfrom++))
  fi
  if ((startfrom==1)); then
    echo "Starting from line labelled 1"
    ((startfrom++))
    ((flag++))
  fi
  echo "Flag=$flag"
  if ((flag<5)); then
    echo "Simulating goto line labelled 1"
    startfrom=1
    continue
  fi
  echo "The End"
  break
done
```

Before you think "Ok, that is the goto I wanted. What a load of overhead you need in bash", look at the second implementation.

```
process_flag() {
  ((flag++))
  echo "Flag=$flag"
  if ((flag<5)); then
    echo "Need to process again"
    return 0
  fi
  return 1
}

flag=0
echo "First time, all statements"
while :; do
  process_flag || break
done
echo "The End"
```

This already looks better. When the function is small, you can put everything in the `loop`.

```
flag=0
echo "First time, all statements"
while :; do
  ((flag++))
  echo "Flag=$flag"
  if ((flag<5)); then
    echo "Need to process again"
    continue
  else
    break
  fi
done
echo "The End"
```

Is this example you can use a different `loop`. Before writing statements for each step, look at the structure and think what control functions you need. Perhaps you want a simple

```
echo "First time, all statements"
for ((flag=1; flag<=5; flag++)); do
  echo "Flag=$flag"
  if ((flag<5)); then
    echo "Need to process again"
  fi
done
echo "The End"
```

When your `loop` has more lines than your screen, consider using a function for the small details.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: this is a terrible idea)

The shell doesn't give you a goto, but you can fabricate one!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo executing before label

# label:

goto() {
    target="$1"
    shift
    exec sh -c "$(sed -e "1,/^# $target:$/d" $0)" "$0" "$@"
}

echo executing from label args: $@

if test "$1" = 5; then
    shift
    goto label "$@"
fi
```

Seriously, don't do this.